Podman Rootless Container-to-Host Communication Not Working Despite Service Listening on Host
I'm trying to set up a rootless Podman environment with containers in the same pod that can communicate with each other, access a non-containerized Java application on the host, and allow the host to communicate with the containers. Here’s the setup and all the steps I’ve tried.
Environment:

Host OS: Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS

Podman Version: 3.4.4
OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Setup: Rootless Podman, single pod with multiple containers


Goal: I want:

Container-to-Container Communication on specific ports inside the pod.
Host-to-Container Communication via specific exposed ports.
Container-to-Host Communication to access a non-containerized Java application running on the host.

Network Configuration:

Pod Ports: 0.0.0.0:10443->1443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:13000->3000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:13306->3306/tcp, 0.0.0.0:14000->4000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:18080->8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:18888->8888/tcp, 0.0.0.0:19201->9201/tcp, 0.0.0.0:11234->12345/tcp, 0.0.0.0:13270->32700/tcp

Host Service:

A Java application on the host, listening on 0.0.0.0:8080, confirmed to be running with ss -tuln | grep 8080.

What I Tried:

Pod Creation with Exposed Ports:

Created the pod with all required ports exposed at the pod level:
podman pod create --name mypod -p 10443:1443 -p 13000:3000 -p 13306:3306 -p 14000:4000 -p 18080:8080 -p 18888:8888 -p 19201:9201 -p 11234:12345 -p 13270:32700


Added containers to the pod without using -p or --publish flags, since all network configurations are handled at the pod level.


Host-to-Container and Container-to-Container Communication:

Host-to-container works fine via localhost:<host_port>.
Container-to-container communication works as expected over localhost:<port>.


Container-to-Host Communication Attempts:

Tried using curl http://host.containers.internal:8080 and curl http://10.88.0.1:8080 (after confirming 10.88.0.1 as the gateway IP for Podman’s default network).
Tried different IPs like 10.0.2.2 and 10.0.2.100.
No connection to the host service on 8080 from within the containers, despite the service running on 0.0.0.0:8080 on the host.


Firewall and SELinux Checks:

Temporarily disabled the firewall:
sudo systemctl stop firewalld


Tried setting SELinux to permissive mode:
sudo setenforce 0


None of these changes resolved the issue.


Using --network slirp4netns:allow_host_loopback=true:

Recreated the pod with --network slirp4netns:allow_host_loopback=true to allow loopback access:
podman pod create --name mypod --network slirp4netns:allow_host_loopback=true -p 10443:1443 -p 13000:3000 -p 13306:3306 -p 14000:4000 -p 18080:8080 -p 18888:8888 -p 19201:9201 -p 11234:12345 -p 13270:32700


Still unable to access http://host.containers.internal:8080 or any other expected IP.


Host DNS Resolution:

Tried resolving host.containers.internal inside the container using:
getent hosts host.containers.internal


Confirmed it resolves to 10.0.2.100 but still unable to reach the host service.


Attempting to Use --network host as a Workaround:

Attempted --network host (not officially supported in rootless Podman):
podman pod create --name mypod --network host


Containers could now access the host, but this setup exposed all network interfaces and isn’t ideal.



Summary of Problem:
Container-to-host communication does not work in rootless Podman, despite following various troubleshooting steps. I have confirmed that the service is accessible on 0.0.0.0:8080 on the host, but containers cannot connect to it using host.containers.internal, the gateway IP, or other Podman-recommended methods.
Question:
How can I enable container-to-host communication in rootless Podman? Is there a reliable way to access a host service from containers in a rootless Podman pod, given that the service is listening on all interfaces (0.0.0.0) on the host?
Let me know if there's any other information I should add.

I've had similar requirements (namely, I wanted the container to have access to a proxy on the host). Couldn't recall the debugging specifics, but I couldn't get slirp4netns to work despite my extensive effort. Eventually I got it working with pasta and --map-gw, but I don't think that's available in your version of podman. It is possible for you to upgrade to 24.04 or distrohop?
